# Initial state of component not updating on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, react-props

The component  gets two props (cryptos and crypto respectively) from its parent component.

I'm initiating one of the state properties `selectedCrypto` which is in charge of displaying the value of the first  input with `this.props.crypto`.

The idea is that when the user clicks on one of the cryptos from the list it should render the input with the name of the selected crypto but this is not happening. 
The prop is received fine. I can console.log it on the component and it shows the current crypto but for some reason the state of the component is not getting it on the first render.

Conversor component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import sortBy from 'sort-by';
import numeral from 'numeral';
import styles from '../../style/css/select_style.css';

class Conversor extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedCrypto: props.crypto || {},
            cryptoToConvert: {name: 'USD'},
            amount: 0,
            result: 0
        }
    }

    updateValue (newValue) {
        let result = this.conversorFunc(this.state.amount, newValue, this.state.cryptoToConvert);
        this.setState({
            selectedCrypto: newValue,
            result
        });
    }

    updateValue2(newValue){
        let result = this.conversorFunc(this.state.amount, this.state.selectedCrypto, newValue);
        this.setState({
            cryptoToConvert: newValue,
            result
        });
    }

    converterHandler(event){

        let inputCrypto = this.state.selectedCrypto;
        let ouputCrypto = this.state.cryptoToConvert;

        let result = this.conversorFunc(event.target.value, inputCrypto, ouputCrypto);
        this.setState({result, amount: event.target.value});

    }

    conversorFunc(amount, inputCrypto, ouputCrypto){
        let result;
        if(ouputCrypto.name == 'USD'){
            result = numeral(inputCrypto.price_usd*parseInt(amount)).format('0,0.00');
        }else{
            result = numeral((inputCrypto.price_usd/ouputCrypto.price_usd)*parseInt(amount)).format('0,0.00');
        }
        return result;
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div className='container conversor-container'>
                {console.log(this.state.selectedCrypto)}
                <h4>Currency Converter</h4>
                <div className='input-container'>
                    <input onKeyUp={this.converterHandler.bind(this)} placeholder='Enter Amount To Convert' className='amount form-control' type="text"/>
                    <div className='selectComp-div'>
                        <Select
                            name="crypto-select"
                            value={this.state.selectedCrypto}
                            onBlurResetsInput={false}
                            onSelectResetsInput={false}
                            clearable={false}
                            onChange={this.updateValue.bind(this)}
                            searchable={true}
                            options={this.props.cryptos}
                            labelKey='name'
                            valueKey='name'
                        />
                    </div>
                    <span>to</span>
                    <div className='selectComp-div'>
                        <Select
                            name="crypto-select"
                            value={this.state.cryptoToConvert}
                            clearable={false}
                            onChange={this.updateValue2.bind(this)}
                            searchable={true}
                            options={this.props.cryptos}
                            labelKey='name'
                            valueKey='name'
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className='result-div'>
                        {this.state.amount}{this.state.selectedCrypto.name}={this.state.result}{this.state.cryptoToConvert.name}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Conversor;
```

Web-app: https://crypto-waatch.herokuapp.com/

code: https://github.com/jorgeduardos/CryptoPrices

Comment: Looks like your problem is coming from the `react-select` module.

Comment: @FortuneEkeruo the implementation of react-select is new, I was using a normal select tag and it didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code in github, you shoud implement componentWillReceiveProps on component Conversor, or add a property (ex: isFetching) on state of single_crypto for load the conversor after the fetch is over, because the "fetch" is async.

Example of sceneario one:

```
// conversor
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      selectedCrypto: nextProps.crypto,
    });
}
```

Example of scenario two:

```
render () {
  // ...
  {this.state.isFetching && <Conversor cryptos={this.props.cryptos} crypto={this.props.singleCrypto}/>}
  // ...
}
```

Comment: using componentWillReceiveProps fixed my issue, thxs a lot. What is the difference between componentwillreceiveprops and componentwillmount then ? I'm a little confuse with these two life cyles.

Comment: componentWillMount is first step react's lifecycle, it only will execute once. The componentWillReceiveProps execute each chance on props of component.